# What do I do with my Google Oauth2 token when trying to call the Calendar API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to talk to the Google Calendar API using Ruby. I followed [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#step-2:-send-a-request-to-googles-oauth-2.0-server) to gain consent from a user, and I saved their authorization token and refresh token. I'm following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events) to call the actual API, but I can't find any instructions anywhere about what specifically to actually do with the token. I assume I'm supposed to include it in the API request somewhere, but where?

Anyone use Google Calendar with Oauth before?

Comment: he question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this API nor used Ruby.

But maybe this is part of the documentation you need to read.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#callinganapi

You add a header in your Http request.
In Java (sorry i really don't know anything about Ruby) I do something that looks like this :

`headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

### You need to follow the [Google Calendar API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/ruby) which has function to trigger authentication flow (`def authorize`)

- This function will create a token file that includes the access token and refresh token
- It will refresh automatically the token when necessary and authorize your calendar service
- Once you have an authorized service, you can use it to perform any calls to the API

Sample how to interlink the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/ruby) with the guide for [event creation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events):

```rb
# This part is from the quickstart and includeds token creation and authorization flow
require "google/apis/calendar_v3"
require "googleauth"
require "googleauth/stores/file_token_store"
require "date"
require "fileutils"

OOB_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob".freeze
APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Calendar API Ruby Quickstart".freeze
CREDENTIALS_PATH = "credentials.json".freeze
# The file token.yaml stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
TOKEN_PATH = "token.yaml".freeze
SCOPE = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR_READONLY

##
# Ensure valid credentials, either by restoring from the saved credentials
# files or intitiating an OAuth2 authorization. If authorization is required,
# the user's default browser will be launched to approve the request.
#
# @return [Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials] OAuth2 credentials
def authorize
  client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file CREDENTIALS_PATH
  token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new file: TOKEN_PATH
  authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new client_id, SCOPE, token_store
  user_id = "default"
  credentials = authorizer.get_credentials user_id
  if credentials.nil?
    url = authorizer.get_authorization_url base_url: OOB_URI
    puts "Open the following URL in the browser and enter the " \
         "resulting code after authorization:\n" + url
    code = gets
    credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
      user_id: user_id, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI
    )
  end
  credentials
end

# Initialize the API
service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
service.authorization = authorize
require "google/apis/calendar_v3"
require "googleauth"
require "googleauth/stores/file_token_store"
require "date"
require "fileutils"

OOB_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob".freeze
APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Calendar API Ruby Quickstart".freeze
CREDENTIALS_PATH = "credentials.json".freeze
# The file token.yaml stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
TOKEN_PATH = "token.yaml".freeze
SCOPE = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR_READONLY

##
# Ensure valid credentials, either by restoring from the saved credentials
# files or intitiating an OAuth2 authorization. If authorization is required,
# the user's default browser will be launched to approve the request.
#
# @return [Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials] OAuth2 credentials
def authorize
  client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file CREDENTIALS_PATH
  token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new file: TOKEN_PATH
  authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new client_id, SCOPE, token_store
  user_id = "default"
  credentials = authorizer.get_credentials user_id
  if credentials.nil?
    url = authorizer.get_authorization_url base_url: OOB_URI
    puts "Open the following URL in the browser and enter the " \
         "resulting code after authorization:\n" + url
    code = gets
    credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
      user_id: user_id, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI
    )
  end
  credentials
end

# Initialize the API
service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
service.authorization = authorize

# this part uses service to create an event

event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(
  summary: 'Google I/O 2015',
  location: '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  description: 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  start: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(
    date_time: '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    time_zone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
  ),
  end: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(
    date_time: '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    time_zone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
  ),
  recurrence: [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  attendees: [
    Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventAttendee.new(
      email: 'lpage@example.com'
    ),
    Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventAttendee.new(
      email: 'sbrin@example.com'
    )
  ],
  reminders: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event::Reminders.new(
    use_default: false,
    overrides: [
      Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventReminder.new(
        reminder_method: 'email',
        minutes: 24 * 60
      ),
      Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventReminder.new(
        reminder_method: 'popup',
        minutes: 10
      )
    ]
  )
)

result = service.insert_event('primary', event)
puts "Event created: #{result.html_link}"
```

> All you need to interlink those two code parts is to change the name
>   from `client` to `service` or vice versa.